# NServicebus : {WARN} failed raising transport message with ID = 

Tags: nservicebus

Here's the scenario. 
I am on NServiceBus 3.0.0.1504 (core dll version). I get above warning message when there's an exception on one of the handlers. Queues are setup as DTC. The interesting thing is, though I get this warning message in QA - it successfully retries N number of times and places the message in the error queue. However, in Production, (in few  cases - I haven't seen this happening consistently), it just tries processing the message once and it stops. It didn't put the message in the error queue or neither it retired N Number of times nor it put the message back in the queue.
I don't really see the difference between QA and Prod environment, its the same code base, and we give permission to queues using build scripts.

Here's the stack trace
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport - Failed raising 'transport message received' event for message with ID=1fb282b5-7a9e-41ea-834a-5f6767273324\195311762 NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportMessageHandlingFailedException: Exception of type 'NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportMessageHandlingFailedException' was thrown.
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.DispatchMessageToHandlersBasedOnType(IBuilder builder, IMessage toHandle, Type messageType) in d:\BuildAgent-01\work\NServiceBus.Trunk\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 899
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleMessage(IBuilder builder, TransportMessage m) in d:\BuildAgent-01\work\NServiceBus.Trunk\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 827
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleTransportMessage(IBuilder builder, TransportMessage msg) in d:\BuildAgent-01\work\NServiceBus.Trunk\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 1026
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e) in d:\BuildAgent-01\work\NServiceBus.Trunk\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 975
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg) in d:\BuildAgent-01\work\NServiceBus.Trunk\src\impl\unicast\transport\NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional\TransactionalTransport.cs:line 409

I tried dropping the same message in QA to test the scenario, however, QA seems to work (with the warning exception log).

Questions
1) Why would this exception happen? Has anyone seen in their system? Why is it logged only as a WARN? I looked at the code and it seems to come from catch block of Unicast.cs where it is handling "Exception".

2) Any suggestions to resolve / dig into the issue?

Comment: Do you have the same faultmanager configured in both qa and prod?

Comment: Andreas, I donot have any special settings for fault manager, which I think should mean default "Faults.Forwarder"? Both QA and Prod are running in built in NServiceBus Production profile.

Comment: Looked at the code and I can't see any reason why NSB wouldn't retry. What is the reason that the message fails to process?

Comment: For this particular case , events were coming out of order. Entity was not created before it was trying to update it. We hacked it for now - putting : HandleCurrentMessageLater(). And I also don't see a reason for it to lose messages. I will get more information and debugging details when I see this scenario in production again.